# React Native Linking vs. React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native

I have a use case in which the user should be able to click on a slider that has its data served from server.
The data contains some information that would be used to:

1. Open another view and initialize it with some parameters.
2. Open external app(s) and send data to it.

Can I use the Linking api in react to make it navigate internally within the app or is that reserved only for react navigation? My intuition is to use something like this:

```
Linking.canOpenURL(retrievedDate).then(supported => {
    if (!supported) {
        // use react navigation           
    } else {
        Linking.openURL(retrievedData);
    }
}).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

But I'm not sure if that's going to be the best practice/most generic one?
Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Try https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e and https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html .  You could link back to your own app, sure if you use your app's url scheme, but why would you want to?  You should use react-navigation for navigation within your app.

Answer (score 0):

Linking means you are online and running a web application.

React-Native is for developing (with React type coding) MOBILE apps. A mobile app is not running in a browser and its pages are not linked to URLs. So you should be using the navigation, which creates a certain UI for Android devices and a different UI for IOS (Apple) devices, and allows the user (and/or the programmer) to "navigate" between the "screens".

If for some obscure reason you are developing a web app with React-Native, you can of course use the linking api. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking